File.WriteAllTextAsync is not updating existing file when using Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),fileName)
I am trying to update an existing Menu.json file, using File.WriteAllTextAsync() method.

I am trying to get the file path dynamically from the executing assembly so that I can use the code in other systems too. like below :
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Data/Menu.json");

Although I can read the file data by
string fileData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);

However, I am unable to update the content of this file by the code below.
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, fileData);

Can anyone help me to point out the issue with it? Or explain to me why is this not working.
Below is the full code that I am using
public async Task SetMenuItemAsync(MenuModel menu)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Data/Menu.json");
    string fileData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
    List<MenuModel> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuModel>>(fileData);
    
    items.Add(menu);
    fileData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented);
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, fileData);
}

Note: using static file path is working for me, for example when using path = @"C:\Users..."

What does "I am unable" mean, what happens when you try?

If no error is being thrown then it will be writing the file. If that is the case you are proabably looking at the wrong file when checking to see whether it has worked. Are you sure the path you are checking is the one created at runtime?

Or it's being overwritten every time you rebuild and run the debugger.

The file is not getting overwritten every time.
As I have mentioned I am able to read the content inside file. So, I hope I am looking into the exact file. Or could you please help with the path where should I look for the file?
by "I am unable", I am trying to say, It is not writing any data into the file, although reading it.
